# How to type summation notation with a vertical line in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I need to type the following summation symbol in Latex. Could anyone help me? Literally, there needs to be a vertical line in a summation symbol, and `$\hat{\beta}_2$` is just a subscript. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think @Sigur's comment is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Sigur Your solution has incorrect spacing, just sayin.  For example, try: `x$\clap{$\sum$}\Big\vert_{\hat{\beta}_2}$`

Comment: @sigur worse than that...the `\sum` is wrongly shifted left.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, specially the position of the limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fine adjustments can be made to the `\vert` placement by placing positive or negative lengths in the 2nd argument (horizontal) or 4th argument (vertical) to `\stackinset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
inline: $\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\Big\vert}{\sum} _{\hat{\beta}_2} x_i$
\end{document}
```

[image]